# Android loading images to ImageView from drawable using only the file name

Tags: android, imageview

I need to load an image from drawable to an image view.
The ImageView is part of a ListViewItem, hence I have a large number of items and a large number of images.

When loading, the app parses a JSON file which states, among other information, the file name to be loaded per list item.

for example, "test_a.jpg".

The file "test_a.jpg" is located in "drawable".

I want, on runtime, to load drawable/test_a.jpg, test_b.jpg, big_chief.jpg and so on...

```
 int intCurrImageResourceID = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(strPictureName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

any ideas on how to achieve that?

*** EDIT ****
It turns out that you shouldn't use file extension. So image.jpg is wrong. image is right. Thanks all. Especially @Augusto Carmo.

Comment: use to Picasso for loading to image in image view when images are in large in number.

Comment: It is not best practice to load the images names from the server, although the images exists in the Drawable folder.

Comment: @BhunnuBaba, I might use it but for my MVP no need to do that. Can I use an image name to get a resource Id on runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- updated (correct answer)

A question, in your code, is `strPictureName` equals, for example, to something like this: `"myDogPicture.png"`? If yes, you should remove `".png"` from the string first. Test it :) To get images from drawable with resource ids, you should not use the image extension.

---- old answer

You can achieve this with the following code:

```
// example - your ImageView
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
// suppose the name of your image in drawable/ is my_image_name.jpg.
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image_name);
```

If you already know what the mapping between strings and resource ids will be, what do you think about using enum? example:

```
public enum MyImage{
        CAT_IMAGE("cat.png", R.drawable.cat),
        DOG_IMAGE("dog.png", R.drawable.dog),
        HORSE_IMAGE("horse.png", R.drawable.horse);

        private final String fileName;
        private final int resId;

        MyImage(String fileName, int resId){
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.resId = resId;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param imageFileName
         * @return -1 if image not found
         */
        public int getResId(String imageFileName){
            int resId = -1;
            for (MyImage myImage : MyImage.values()) {
                if (imageFileName.equals(myImage.fileName)){
                    resId = myImage.resId;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return resId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. but I need the value send to "setImageResource" to be R.drawable + strMyImageNameStringVariableToHoldTheActualName. What setImageResource expects is a resource ID, and the challenge is to translate my image name to an ID.

Comment: Thanks but that's not generic enough for my purpose. I really expected my attempt of int intCurrImageResourceID = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(strPictureName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
 to be enough.

Comment: A question, in your code, is `strPictureName` equals, for example, to something like this: `myDogPicture.png`? If yes, you should remove ".png" from the string first. Test it :)

To get images from drawable with resource ids, you should not use the image extension.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you :). I edited the answer so others can see what was wrong. If you do not mind, could you set this as the correct answer? Cheers ^^